# Можно ли app.js и controller.js запаковать в один .min.js?

Tags: angularjs

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/internet',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/internet_i.html'
})
.when('/telephony',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/telephony_i.html'
})
.when('/ip_tv',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/ip_tv_i.html'
})
.when('/data_tr',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/data_tr_i.html'
})
});
```

controller/controller.js

```
 app.controller('internet');
 app.controller('telephony');
 app.controller('ip_tv');
 app.controller('data_tr');
```

и все вместе, но не работает что-то про $injector:modulerr ругается

```
var app=angular.module("app",["ngRoute"]);app.config(function(t){t.when("/internet",{templateUrl:"pages/internet_i.html"}).when("/telephony",{templateUrl:"pages/telephony_i.html"}).when("/ip_tv",{templateUrl:"pages/ip_tv_i.html"}).when("/data_tr",{templateUrl:"pages/data_tr_i.html"})}),app.controller("internet"),app.controller("telephony"),app.controller("ip_tv"),app.controller("data_tr");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При минификации теряются имена импортируемых зависимостей, необходимо добавить явную аннотацию.

Для app.js будет выглядеть так:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/internet',{
        templateUrl : 'pages/internet_i.html'
    })
    .when('/telephony',{
        templateUrl : 'pages/telephony_i.html'
    })
    .when('/ip_tv',{
        templateUrl : 'pages/ip_tv_i.html'
    })
    .when('/data_tr',{
        templateUrl : 'pages/data_tr_i.html'
    });
}]);
```

Для контроллеров делается аналогично. Описание аннотаций [доки](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Еще рекомендую сразу добавить `ng-strict-di` рядом с `ng-app` для автоматической проверки аннотаций [доки](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

И есть автоматическая подстановка аннотаций при минификации, например для babel https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate

Comment: ответ четкий спасибо! есть хоть пища для куда копать